# How to loop through each row within a dataframe that contains a string, and match such string to each item in a list?

Tags: python, string, matching

Dear Stackoverflow community-

I have a dataframe df, that has a row 'name' which contains different names in it:

```
print(df)

name
tom
jerry
steven
Zeo
```

Then I have a list with names in it:

```
print(list)

['tom', 'zeo']
```

How do I create a new column in df, df['matched'], that will return the matched value from the list to the column if matched, and nan otherwise?

```
name   matched
tom    tom
jerry   nan
steven  nan
Zeo     zeo
```

I tried:

```
for i in list:
    df['matched']=df['name'].str.lower().str.contains(i,case=False).map({True:i,False:np.nan})
```

But it does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using `str.extract` here with a regex alternation:

```py
names = ["tom", "zeo", ...]
regex = r'^(' + r'|'.join(names) + r')$'
df["matched"] = df["name"].str.extract(regex)
```

Output:

```
     name matched
0     tom     tom
1   jerry     NaN
2  steven     NaN
3     Zeo     zeo
```

Comment: @ScottBoston It isn't clear that the OP wants a case insensitive search.  Even so, I would probably just add `(?i)` to the regex.